# Valid AssetBundle Throws Null Reference Exception (NRE) With Any API Call

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, asset-pipeline, assets, assetbundle

**This question is not about what a null reference is, this question is about why a valid AssetBundle is throwing an NRE in an API I cannot step through**

I have been converting my project from using the Resource folder to AssetBundles. I have tagged my scriptable objects in the "scriptableobjects" asset bundle, and I've loaded and stored that bundle in the "Assets/AssetBundles" folder.

Here the code where I build my assets:

```
public class AssetBundleManager
{
    [MenuItem("Assets/Build AssetBundles")]
    static void BuildAllAssetBundles()
    {
        string assetBundleDirectory = "Assets/AssetBundles";
        if (!Directory.Exists(assetBundleDirectory))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(assetBundleDirectory);
        }

        //https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundles-Building.html
        BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles(assetBundleDirectory,
                                        BuildAssetBundleOptions.UncompressedAssetBundle,
                                        BuildTarget.StandaloneWindows);
    }
}
```

Before looking at the code below, here is proof that the AssetBundle is not null when it is going to be used:

[image]

After building the assets, I then go to actually load these assets and their resources:

```
public class X_AssetBundleManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static Maps _maps;
    private static AssetBundle _scriptableObjectsBundle;

    public static T LoadScriptableObject<T>(string assetName) where T : ScriptableObject
    {
        if (_scriptableObjectsBundle == null)
        {
            AssetBundle _scriptableObjectsBundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile("Assets/AssetBundles/scriptableobjects");
            if (_scriptableObjectsBundle == null)
            {
                Debug.Log("Failed to load 'scriptableobjects' AssetBundle!");
                return null;
            }
        }

        if (_scriptableObjectsBundle.Contains(assetName)) // NRE HERE
        {
            Debug.Log("DOES CONTAIN");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("DOES NOT CONTAIN");
        }

        try
        {
            // NRE HERE
            var all = _scriptableObjectsBundle.LoadAllAssets();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogError(e);
        }

        T obj = _scriptableObjectsBundle.LoadAsset<T>(assetName); // NRE HERE
        if (obj == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Failed to load " + assetName + "  in scriptableobjects");
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

The `_scriptableObjects` variable is not null. Its a valid object. However, calling ANY api on it causes a null reference exception.

I can't even step through the code to see whats null. The AssetBundle itself is not null, but any call causes this.

Any advice on how to further debug this issue or what the problem might be?

Comment: Yea just a typo sorry. @Ruzihm I removed the template for clarity

Comment: @derHugo so maybe it was a duplicate all along .. wouldn't checking for null immediately before the NRE step have revealed that it was in fact null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in

```
AssetBundle _scriptableObjectsBundle = ...
```

you overrule (hide) your already existing field variable equally named `_scriptableObjectsBundle` ... so this outer field `_scriptableObjectsBundle` still remains `null`! and the one you actually assign only exists within the

```
if(_scriptableObjectsBundle == null)
```

block → simply remove this additional  `AssetBundle`

```
_scriptableObjectsBundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile("Assets/AssetBundles/scriptableobjects");
```

Comment: Yes thank you, I had it as a static and it was being overriden. Thank you for pointing that out